# mat-radio-button not getting focus inside a mat-menu

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

I have a menu where the user can change the language, and has other options like sign out and settings. I want to make this menu accessible using the keyboard. The problem it is only working for the `mat-menu-item` and not for the `mat-radio-buttons`. The radio buttons are not getting focused at all.

When adding `mat-menu-item` directive to the `mat-radio-button`, I get the following error:

> More than one component is matched on this element: MatMenuItem ([mat-menu-item]) and MatRadioButton (mat-radio-button)

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lang-selection-menu?file=src/app/menu-icons-example.html)

Comment: Do you just want the radio buttons to be focused on hover ?

Comment: @IshCoo93 I want the radio buttons to be reachable with keyboard up/down. This is now only possible for the other elements in the menu, but not for the radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the radio button options as separate menu items and programmatically set the value for the radio buttons when the menu is selected.

The code is given below

**menu-icons-exampe.html**

```html
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item style="height: fit-content;" (click)="language=1">
  <mat-radio-group class="grid">
    <mat-radio-button value="1" [checked]="language==2">Option 1</mat-radio-button>

  </mat-radio-group>
  </button>
   <button mat-menu-item style="height: fit-content;" (click)="language=2">
  <mat-radio-group class="grid" >
    <mat-radio-button value="2" [checked]="language==2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>

  </mat-radio-group>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voice mail</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

and in your component declare a variable "language" as shown below

menu-icons-example.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'menu-icons-example',
  templateUrl: 'menu-icons-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-icons-example.scss']
})
export class MenuIconsExample {
  public language: any
}
```

Comment: looks good, thanks :) But if I want to take it a step further and move all the radio buttons to a separate reusable component, this will not work again. Do you have any ideas for that?